# Check for value in array, remove if true

Tags: jquery, html, arrays

I have a grid of images, each with a `data-image` attribute and value.

When a user selects an image, its `data-image` attributes's value is added to an array.

I want the code to work so that when the user clicks an item, if the item already is in the array (that is, if the user has clicked on it before), then it gets removed.

Like a select/de-select option.

HTML

```
<div class="fifth" data-image="1">
    <div class="full clearfix relative">
        <img src="image.png" />

        <div class="overlay"></div>

    </div>
    <div class="options">
        <h4 class="txt-white left">#0001</h4>
        <h4 class="right txt-gold select-image" data-image="1">Select</h4>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
var images = [];
var price = $('.order').data('price');

    // select
    $('.select-image').on('click', function() {

        $(this).parent().parent().toggleClass('selected');
        $(this).toggleClass('selected');

        if( $(this).hasClass('selected') ) {
            $(this).html('&#10005;');
        } else {
            $(this).html('Select');
        }

        images = $.grep(images, function(value) {
            return value != $(this).data('image');
        });

        console.log(images);

        images.push($(this).data('image'));

        var items = images.length;

        $('.total-price').html(items*price);

    });
```

But, I can't seem to figure out how `$.grep` works. Any ideas?

[UPDATE]

[Here's a JS Fiddle of what I have so far, you can see the issue here.](http://jsfiddle.net/zzgF6/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to use `$.grep` here, a native [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) and [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) will suffice.

```
var images = [], image, index;
$('.select-image').on('click', function() {
    // ....
    image = $(this).data('image');
    // Lookup image in array
    index = images.indexOf(image);
    if(~index){ // ~ makes index evaluate as boolean (not really though)
         // If found, remove that entry from the array
         images.splice(index, 1);
    }else{
         // Otherwise, add it to the array
         images.push(image);
    }
    // ....
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Grep loops through an array in pretty much the same way as $.each with one exception. If you return true from the callback, the element is retained. Otherwise, it is removed from the array.

Your code should look something like this:

```
items = $.grep(items, function (el, i) {
if (i === 5) { // or whatever
    return false;
}

// do your normal code on el

return true; // keep the element in the array
});
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the explanation. So, if I wanted to update the array I'd `return el != $(this).data('image');` , where you've put `return false;` ?

Comment: yup - a return true will keep it, a return false will remove it :)

Comment: Hmm, struggling to see how this will be worked into the code I have, I've updated my question at the bottom with what I have. Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Comment: @lukeseager seems like you have it all right.. try instead of: `if (i === $(this).data('image')) {`  
use 
`if (i === $(this).attr('data-image')) {`

Comment: Hmm, Doesn't seem to work. I have a JS fiddle of the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/zzgF6/1/

Comment: your $(this) is geting redefined somewhere to window.. you need to assign that at the top ... `var $this = $(this);` to hold it. apply your operations to that instead. otherwise code looks sound.

Answer (score 0):

Grep takes an array and performs a function for each element in this array.
This function returns true or false, depending on a given criteria. 
Grep will then return every element for which the function returned true in an array.

```
$.grep( images, function($arrayElement, index) {
  return $arrayElement.attr("data-anything") == "yes i like fish";
});
```

I am not quite sure why you would need to use grep on a grid of images; 
How about giving a ".selected"-Class and use this in order to filter out the elements that have been selected?

**Edit:**
You are basically asking for the not-case. You want to selected elements which do not have a certain value.

```
var a_preselected_value = 9;

var images_with_one_id_deselected = $.grep( images, function($arrayElement, index) {
  return $arrayElement.data("image") != a_preselected_value;
});
```

Comment: The idea is the user is selected images they wish to buy. As they select them, the total selected is used to work out the price, and the array of image ID's is stored so the system knows what they have purchased :)

But if they de-select an image, I need the array to update so the price is reduced and the item is removed from the array.

Comment: In that case I understand where you are coming from.
JF it`s answer should be what you want. 

return $arrayElement.data("image") != A_DESELECTED_VALUE;

Should be what you want to happen in your grep callback. 

The images-Array returned by grep will not contain an element having the data-image-value of `A_DESELECTED_VALUE`.

Comment: Hmm, I'm still struggling for some reason. Here's a JS fiddle of what I have if that helps: http://jsfiddle.net/zzgF6/1/

Comment: I might have done the whole thing slightly different and probably would have avoided the use of $.grep altogether (though it can be a neat function to have).

However, here is a fiddle which might solve your problem: http://jsfiddle.net/Pebqa/

The trick is to trigger pushing and filtering on whether or not selection or deselection has taken place.

---

Be aware, that 'el' corresponds to the current element or value in the array at the index 'i'. Comparing with 'i', as seen in your original fiddle, would not have worked.